# Excel Pivot Table Input across two Columns

Tags: excel, pivot

I am surprised this was not asked before; at least I could not find the answer.

I have data for a pivot table in two columns and would like to have the pivot table treat those two columns as if there was only one column. Is there a simple way to do this? Of course I could copy column two at the end of column one but in my actual case I have 2 million rows and then this would not be possible.

Here the simple example:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating two tables and then appending them with power query:

1- Select the range in column A

2- Click the `Data` menu

3- Click `From Table/Range`

4- Create the table (OK)
(this will open the power query window)

5- From the dropdown `Close & Load` select `Close & Load To ..`

6- Select `Only Create Connection`

7- Select the range in column B

8- Repeat steps 2 to 4

9- Select `Append Queries`

10- In the dropdown select the first table created

11- From the dropdown `Close & Load` select `Close & Load To`

12- Select `Pivot Table Report`

Now you have a data source for your Pivot table with both columns combined, please note that both columns should have the same name for the Append query to work as desired.

Comment: Is it possible to do this for many columns without manually repeating steps 2 to 4? For another task I need to create a Pivot table from data in 10,000 rows with up to 1000 columns. Too many cells to squeeze it all into 1 or 2 columns in Excel.

Comment: @Gecko in Power Query Transform tab, you can select all the columns and then Unpivot. It will be 10M values, so I don't know if it's going to hold or break, or how fast will be but it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing,  easier for multiple columns
You can do this by creating two tables and then appending them with power query:

1- Select all the columns

2- Click the Data menu

3- Click From Table/Range

4- Create the table (OK) (this will open the power query window)

5- Select menu Transform

6- Select all the columns

7- Select Unpivot Columns

8- Select menu Home

9- From the dropdown Close & Load select Close & Load To

10- Select Pivot Table Report

Comment: I followed all the steps but at 10 there is no option "Pivot Table Report". This is the dialog box I can see: https://imgur.com/a/YooYz3q.

Comment: I don't know why that option is not showing for you, but what you can do is save it as 'create connection only' , then you can go to insert pivot table as usual. Wwhen it asks you to select the range or source, select external data source and choose connection. The connection should show in there for you to create the pivot table.